# d3.js using .attr() after each()?

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to use selection.attr() after selection.each()? I have the following simple code:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()...;

chart
    .selectAll('.gw')
    .selectAll('path.line')
    .each(function(d, i) {
        $this.computeXXX(d, ....);
    })
    .attr('d', line);
```

I've checked that the 'attr' function is being called, but for some reason when I go back and try to check the 'path' elements that make up the selection, they never have the 'd' attribute set. What's the return from the 'each' call? I checked the d3 API docs and it didn't mention that there was any type of return value, yet there does seem to be.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use `.attr()` after `.each()`. I've made a [very ugly example](http://tributary.io/inlet/5158278) based on a pre-made chart from [tributary](http://tributary.io/). Anyway, you can see it uses `.each()` to draw an orange stroke and then modifies other attributes after. If you post more details of your code or put in on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or tributary we/I can probably help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks. You are certainly correct. My problem was actually elsewhere, in that I didn't yet understand how the line() function and the value in the data for each element were being used. A bunch more experimentation fixed all that. Definitely my own fault!